What happens if there is an impedance mismatch on differential pairs?
What do we encounter if the impedance changes along the way? For example, what kind of problem can we encounter when one of the two complementary PCB's is 90 ohm and the other is 100 ohm? For example, can we say that when it is halved, it drops to approximately 95 ohms? In this case, will there be a loss of speed or will the connection be completely disconnected?

Is there a reason this is specific to differential? Would the question not be answered by a single-ended transmission line? What "complementary PCBs"? What would be halved? What speed or connection -- you seem to be implying some signaling on the medium, but what? Finally, is there an underlying purpose to this question, might it help us answer your question by knowing what you are doing?

See reflection coefficient. One source: https://www.everythingrf.com/community/what-is-reflection-coefficient

@TimWilliams I asked that because I usually work with differential lines. But of course, single ended lines are included. I perform tests by connecting two or more PCBs. (we can think of it as backplane and daugher card). There are many different lines (displayport, hdmi, ethernet) I want to verify these lines and I am designing a daughter card. and these lines just go from connector to connector. I'm curious about the expected reactions if there is an impedance mismatch between these cards.

This is one of those occasions when asking a question that is too specific won't easily permit answers that allow you to learn about the way transmission lines work and, you may not realize that this is related to transmission lines (nor have ever heard of them) but, transmission line theory is key on this occasion @esat

I'm sure this is a duplicate of some distant question, but the dearth of direct answers in search results, suggests to me this is another ever-green topic. I won't vote to close, but the answer is common textbook fodder (see above; see also, digital signal quality topics) if anyone wants to write it up.

To clarify, you're asking about differential pairs - are you asking what happens if one (e.g: positive) is 90Ω, and the other (e.g: negative) is 100Ω? (that doesn't really make sense)... or are you asking what happens if a given pair is routed as 90Ω for one section and then 100Ω for another section?

@Attie exactly 2nd one. The length matching and differential routing is OK.  what happens if a given pair is routed as 90Ω for one section and then 100Ω for another section? its a exact question for me.

As noted, this is part of transmission line theory. This is a very big subject, so I will simply focus on your specific question.
Consider your question, which can be represented as below (I have used single ended but the theory holds for differential)

The impedance mismatch will result in a reflection given by the reflection coefficient gamma \$\Gamma = \frac {Zl - Zo} {Zl + Zo} \$ where Zl is the load (here 90 ohms).
That yields \$\Gamma = \frac {90 - 100} {90 + 100} \$ = -0.05263 so the magnitude of the reflection is about 5% out of phase.
[The sign indicates whether the reflection is in phase (+) or out of phase (-)].
In practice, a 5% reflection can be acceptable depending on the specifics.
Whether this is an issue depends on the edge rate of the signal; where the propagation delay of the signal is higher than about 1/10 of the distance being travelled then we need to treat the interconnect as a transmission line (rule of thumb - this varies from 4 to 10 in practice depending on who you ask).
Propagation in most flavours of FR-4 is 160 pSec / inch (surface) and 175 pSec / inch (inner layers).
The impedances will not 'average'.

This is an excellent video for a more visual demonstration of reflections. https://youtu.be/2AXv49dDQJw?t=646s

Zl is equal to the second line's Z0 only if it is ideally terminated.
